# Django - Data from view not rendered in template

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having quite some troubles understanding how variables are passed to templates in Django, I'm new so keep this in mind.
My problem is that, when the URL is loaded data from databases can't be rendered except for the **user**(request.user.username) which is strangely loaded.
I even tried to declare variables inside the view's def but even them are not rendered

The model is imported inside the views.py.

My idea is that, since the **user** from request.user is loaded, there must be some problem with loading the database model, but this doesn't explain why even freshly declared variables inside the view's def are not passed.

In the **/admin** page all the models work fine.

Below are the fragments of my code, they should be enough to understand the problem, if not I can upload other parts.

Thank you in advance.

---

**views.py:**

```
def load_main(request):
    diet_list = DietTable.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'main/main.html',
                  {
                      'diet_list': diet_list,
                      'user': request.user.username,
                  })
```

**part in the main.html:**

```
<body>
...
<header>
...
</header>
...
{% block content %}

    <strong>
        {{ user }}

        {% for element in diet_list %}
            {{ element }}
        {% endfor %}
    </strong>

{% endblock %}
...
</body>
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include


from main import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.load_main, name='main_view'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
...

class DietTable(models.Model):
   diet_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # to not use the default 'id; given by django
   dietName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   dietType = models.ForeignKey(DietTypes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   startDate = models.DateTimeField()
   dayLength = models.IntegerField()

   def __str__(self):
       return str(str(self.dietName) + "(" + str(self.dayLength) + ")")
...
```

Comment: So what's the problem with it, it should be rendered.

Comment: Even if you remove `user` from the context it will still be rendered, since that is added from a context processor that is used by default. My guess is that the view that you think is being run is not the one actually being run.

Comment: You make the migrations before run the server?

Comment: so... what happens?

Comment: Yes, I made all the migrations, as said in the admin page, the models all work fine.
@AbdulAzizBarkat how can I be sure the view I think is running is the actual running one?

Comment: Hello @Mes are you extending any template inside you **main.html** ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari no I'm not

Comment: Hello @Mes try to print **diet_list** insde your function and you don't have to pass user as context inside **main.html** because django does that for you and you can access your user in template directly eg.(`{{reques.user.username}}`)